# Connect (SSH) to the same server, through two different gateways, with different server users

Tags: ssh, networking, ssh-tunneling

What I would like to achieve is to be able to connect to some `target.server` from my local machine, without having to type any passwords, with the following commands:

```
ssh user1@target.server
ssh user2@target.server
```

Each user above only accepts a connection from a specific IP address, corresponding to respectively `gateway1.example` and `gateway2.example`. I have added all necessary SSH keys to the right `authorized_keys`, so that I can do, without typing passwords:

- `ssh gateuser1@gateway1.example` from local machine, then `ssh user1@target.server` from `gateway1`.
- `ssh gateuser2@gateway2.example` from local machine, then `ssh user2@target.server` from `gateway2`.

Now I think it remains to put the right things in my local `~/.ssh/config`. When I add:

```
Host target.server
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser1@gateway1.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

Then `ssh user1@target.server` works. But I don't know how to make both `user1` and `user2` work. I tried:

```
Host target.server
    User user1
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser1@gateway1.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
Host target.server
    User user2
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser2@gateway2.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

or

```
Host target.server
    User user1
        ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser1@gateway1.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
    User user2
        ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser2@gateway2.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

but it still didn't work for `user2`: all went through `gateway1` and not `gateway2`.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

**Update:** I've been able to make the following commands work:

```
ssh user1
ssh user2
```

(without `@target.server`), using the following configuration:

```
Host user1
    HostName target.server
    User user1
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser1@gateway1.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
Host user2
    HostName target.server
    User user2
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser2@gateway2.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

This is what I will be using, but I'm still curious to see a solution to the two commands at the beginning of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you figured out, aliases are a good solution. If you don't want to use them, the `Match` directive might be another valid option.

```
Host target.server
    Match User user1
        ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser1@gateway1.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
    Match User user2
        ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' gateuser2@gateway2.example 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

From the `ssh_config` man page:

> **Match**   Restricts the following declarations (up to the next **Host** or **Match** keyword) to be used only when the conditions following the **Match** keyword are satisfied.

Comment: I tested and it worked! Great answer. Thank you!